# how to search a phrase in every two lines with sed

Tags: bash, search, sed

I wanna search a phrase in a doc.
But maybe the phrase was broken up into two lines.
So what I want to do is:
Search in :
line1 and line2
line2 and line3
line3 and line4
......

I am a beginner, and I wanna practise using sed.
So, how can I do this with sed?
Any ideas?

---

This does not work.

```
$ sed 'N;s/line2.line3/line23/' test.txt 
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

1)sed read first line and second line,then search.
2)sed read third line and fourth line,then search.
......
So if the phrase in the line2 and line3, I will miss it.
Can I read the previous line?

---

update

Thanks for @Beta 's help.

```
sed '$!N;s/line2.line3/line23/;P;D;'
```

It works. But I'm still a little confused.
There're still some questions.

I have read the manual.

> n:read the next line of input into the pattern space.
>   N:append the next line of input into the pattern space.
>   d:Delete pattern space.  Start next cycle.
>   D:Delete up to the first embedded newline in the pattern space.  Start next cycle, but skip reading from the input if there is still data in the pattern space.

```
sed -n 'N;P' test.txt
```

1)sed read first and second line, then print the first line.
2)sed empty its pattern space then read third and fourth line, then print the third line.
Am I right?

```
sed -n 'N;P;D' test.txt
```

1)sed read first and second line, then print the first line.
2)sed do not empty its pattern space then read third, then print the second line.
Am I right?

Why the "next line" has different behaviors in the COMMAND N and n in the 2 commands above?

```
sed '$!N;s/line2.line3/line23/;P;D;'
```

ps.I think "$!" is not necessary.

Comment: Give some examples of input file and expected output with the broken phrases in multiple lines...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is more than one way to do it. This is close to what you tried:

```
sed '$!N;s/line2.line3/line23/;P;D;'
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But I am still a little confused with "n", "N" and "D". I update my questions. Could you help me again please? PS:I think "$!" in the commands which you provided is not necessary.